# Better way to change parent's state when child's onClick is triggered? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Given the simplified component structure:

```
A -> B -> C

example
A {
   return <B ... />
}

B {
   return <C ... />;
}
```

call structure

```
A{onChange} -> B {isOpen} -> C {onClick}
```

**How do you change B's isOpen state when C's onClick is triggered? without C knows?**

```
- call **B's method to change isOpen** in C's onClick.
- FYI, I call A's onChange in C's onClick too.
```

My Solution

```
C {
  onClick() {
     this.props.toggleIsOpen(); // << But the requirement is that C should not even know this. 
          // How do I delete this line and still work?
     this.props.onChange();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a function in `B`, pass it to `C`, and then call it in `C`'s `onClick` handler.

That way, `C` is completely agnostic as to what that function does, and you get the desired functionality.

Comment: C shouldn't know the parent B exists.

Comment: that's the requirement. unfortunately.

Comment: And what part of my answer suggests to you that C knows anything about B?

Answer (score 0):

`C` has to call `B`'s method but `C` is not dependant on `B`'s method if you do something like

```
C {
  onClick() {
     this.props.toggleIsOpen && this.props.toggleIsOpen();
     this.props.onChange();
  }
}
```

or you could use the onChange function from `A` to change the state and pass it to `B` via props